# problem using ffmpeg drawtext for rtl languge

Tags: linux, macos, video, ffmpeg, right-to-left

i use this command to write on a video:

```
 ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf drawtext=\"text_shaping=1:fontfile=font.ttf:
    text='یه نوشته فارسی!': fontcolor=black: fontsize=$font_size: box=1: boxcolor=black@0:boxborderw=0: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2 :enable='between(t,5,10)'\"  -c:a copy -force_key_frames 0:05:00,0:6:00 end.mp4
```

it work fine when i don't have numbers and symbols(!,?,$ and ...) in first and end of my text.
my lang is right to left and this commmand not support rtl.
what i must do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, *the issue isn't really rtl or FFMPEG related*. If you want to use characters like **"!"** you need to *escape them*. 
I was able to draw the text without any issues by escaping the exclamation mark (like this: `text='مرحبا بيتر\!'`), without any other special measures taken.

Secondly, you should always *be careful of leaving whitespace inside filters* or in between *filter parameters*.

Thirdly, when asking questions it's always better to *provide additional details* (like **reports**, **logs** etc.) and not general statements like "it's not working".

I know it's already an old question, but I really hope this helps you and/or other people.

Comment: @Soroush Tayyebi, at least you should acknoledge the answer!